# how to draw a rectangle in HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to draw a rectangle and I found the website for css code(http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). How do I put together in HTML? In other words, how do I define #rectangle in HTML.

Facebook always has blue rectangle at the top of each page. What is the best way to achieve like them?

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Uh... `<div></div>`.

Comment: Otherwise, you could draw it in HTML5 http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: You know by default every html block level element is a rectangle.

Answer (score 59):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brMPs/)

HTML

```
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

CSS

```
#rectangle{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

I strongly suggest you read about [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) and [the basics of HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction).

Comment: Thank you very much. #rectangle acts like a method in Java, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, HTML and CSS are not programming languages and do not have methods or functions. CSS is just applying a certain style to the element with the id "rectangle". I guess in a way it is "calling" the #rectangle "method"...

Comment: For empty rectangles - http://jsfiddle.net/afj9eu4r/

Answer (score 18):

## SVG

Would recommend using svg for graphical elements.
While using css to style your elements.

```css
#box {
  fill: orange;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect id="box" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually gives a `<rect>` element, which is presumably what the questioner wanted, not a `<div>` element.

Answer (score 14):

Use `<div id="rectangle" style="width:number px; height:number px; background-color:blue"></div>`

This will create a blue rectangle.

Comment: Y u use inline CSS-style?

Comment: So it is easy to copy/paste in one go

Comment: for the ones using this site correctly. this is good. you shouldn't come here to learn CSS and HTML anyways. although both options would be the best.

Answer (score 7):

To mimic the rectangle with fixed position on facebook, try something like this:

```
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#rectangle {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:#00f;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I do the following in my eBay listings:

```
<p style="border:solid thick darkblue; border-radius: 1em; 
          border-width:3px; padding-left:9px; padding-top:6px; 
          padding-bottom:6px; margin:2px; width:980px;">
```

This produces a box border with rounded corners.You can play with the variables.

Answer (score 4):

the css you are showing must be applied to a block element, like a div.
So :

```
<div id="#rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was a joke. :)

Comment: A1rPun has a fever and the only prescription is more jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify your sections and then style them with CSS.  In this case, this might work:

HTML

```
<div id="blueRectangle"></div>
```

CSS

```
#blueRectangle {
    background: #4679BD;
    min-height: 50px;
    //width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PJ5q/

Answer (score 2):

In the HTML page you have to to put your css code between the  tags, while in the body a div which has as id rectangle. Here the code:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#rectangle 
{
   all your css code
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="rectangle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
.example {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="retangulo">
   
</div>
```